# Objective Zip problems getting started

Tags: objective-c, ios, zip

I am trying to use objective zip (v1.01e) in an IOS4 application as I want the ability to send password protected zip files via email.

I have got the objective zip source code files in my application, but am experiencing some problems following this getting started guide. http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/wiki/GettingStarted

I use the following command

```
ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:@"yourFiles.zip" mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
```

But this always fails returning null via the code shown below from method zipOpen2 (line 507). Here:

```
if (ziinit.filestream == NULL)
        return NULL;
```

Following the stack trace it passes though the following methods:

```
//First
- (id) initWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName mode:(ZipFileMode)mode 

//Second
extern zipFile ZEXPORT zipOpen (pathname, append)

//Third
extern zipFile ZEXPORT zipOpen2 (pathname, append, globalcomment, pzlib_filefunc_def)
```

However, I notice the second method has this code.

```
extern zipFile ZEXPORT zipOpen (pathname, append)
    const char *pathname;
    int append;
{
    return zipOpen2(pathname,append,NULL,NULL);
}
```

When I query the value of the string pathname (in GDB) from this method on I get:

0x1b7f30 does not appear to point to a valid object.

So my questions:

1. What is `const char *pathname`, what does it do and is it messing up the pathname? AFAIK char is a single character which cant possibly represent a file name??
2. The code shown comes from source code of the objective zip project and not my own so I assume its working. It may be my misunderstanding of it. So what other possible reasons could be causing this problem?

For some more info `initWithFileName:` takes the parameter, filename and passes it on to `zipOpen()` by creating a pointer to file name as follows.

```
_fileName = [fileName retain];
```

Comment: have you checked pathname in zipopen2 method by nslog?

Comment: Thankyou, I'm trying to do that, to use NSLog I must inport #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>, but this causes compilation errors in NSObjCRuntime.h. I don't know why it would do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Optionally you can use: printf("%s",pathname);

Comment: Perfect, NSLog was giving me the dreaded Exc Bad Access error.

Comment: Okay. here it is working with me correctly so might be some issue in passing path name. check it properly looks like it is released.

Comment: Do I have to pass the name and path or just the name? Are there some permissions I need to set somewhere?

Comment: "What is const char *pathname, what does it do and is it messing up the pathname? AFAIK char is a single character which cant possibly represent a file name??" <- I just LOL'd on this. You should seriously learn C before messing with iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your advice the answer was that I was not appending the application's directory to the beginning of the file name.

Comment: H2C03, I cut my teeth in Java and I think thats the problem here.

Comment: @AndrewS, if your problem is solved, you should write your own answer and mark it as solved. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to solve this problem. The issue was because I was not appending the application's documents directory location to the beginning of the  file name.

Once I did this all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I've [traced the file opening back to fopen](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/source/browse/trunk/Objective-Zip/MiniZip/ioapi.c#85), which is good news because now you can [find out what the error is using `errno`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strerror/). Until you tell us what `errno` you're getting I can only guess what the problem is. But, if I were to guess I'd say it's failing because you don't have the correct permissions to write to that file.

Comment: Thanks for responding. As mentioned above the error resulted from me not passing the dir along with the file name. School boy error. However, the problem stemmed from the tutorial not indicating that you needed to supply one.